# Trying to import numpy but VSCode gives me pylint(import-error)?

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code

I used command prompt to install numpy by using the following commands

```
pip3 install numpy
```

and

```
python.exe -m install numpy
```

and it's installed it in my appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation etc folder.

However when trying to import numpy in my python fil in VSCode it gives me "Unable to import 'numpy' pylint(import-error)"

Not sure what the deal is. I've imported other libraries before like discord.py in the same way and it's worked for me. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's because python interpreter couldn't detect numpy in the current working environment. It's recommended to create a virtual environment via `python -m venv <name>` in current working folder, then reinstall numpy. There will be no error shown. About virtual environment, reference: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_global-virtual-and-conda-environments

Comment: It still gives me the same error, I used ```python -m venv .venv``` in the folder where my .py file is and installed numpy there using ```pip3 install numpy``` but it still said "requirement met, installed in" in my appdata folder and the error persists.

Comment: how about uninstalling the existed modules and reinstalling it again? can you post the error screenshot to the question?

Comment: Have you activated the virtual environment which you just created?

Comment: I wasn't aware that I was supposed to activate it, but even after activating it gives me the same error https://imgur.com/a/b52T8CE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing `numpy`, use `pip show numpy` to check if it was installed in current environment:

[image]

Then press the green button on the upper right corner, run the file in Terminal.

The module `py` usage is:

[image]

So the right command is `py test.py -3`, also it's recommended that use the command `python` to run .py file.

[image]

Comment: Never mind it didn't actually fix the issue, just tested it https://i.imgur.com/eJ2Sp2z.png

Comment: @chimps123. I've edit my answer and you can have a look at it.