# VS Code more readable algebraic expressions extension in Python

Tags: visual-studio-code, spyder

I am working with algebraic expressions in Python.
I would like to know if exists any VS Code extension to automatically view expressions in a more human-friendly way.
For example:

```
x*y*math.e**(-x**2-y**2)
```

[image]

Comment: which one are you using currently, if any?

Comment: @BZKN My objetive is if I write the first one in my IDE, I can see the second one automatically. I am using VS Code but no problem for me if I have to change the IDE.

Comment: if you are flexible to change the IDE, I can update my answer to recommend one more to make your choice easier.

Comment: It would be perfect!

Answer (score 1):

I have used below two mainly for mathematical expressions:

---

- [Symplex](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=zalo.symplex):
  Symplex requires that Python and SymPy are installed. It can be installed with pip install SymPy.

---

- [Numpy](https://numpy.org/): Why Numpy? Because of [algebraic-expressions-in-python are best sorted by Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258348/algebraic-expressions-in-python).  However, Numpy extension on VS code is also not straightforward. Check please following SO sources for you to get Numpy in your VS code:

  - [No module named 'numpy': Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40185437/no-module-named-numpy-visual-studio-code)
  - [Trying to import numpy but VSCode gives me pylint(import-error)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64111656/trying-to-import-numpy-but-vscode-gives-me-pylintimport-error)
  - [Problems: install NumPy on visual studio code with jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64628539/problems-install-numpy-on-visual-studio-code-with-jupyter)

---

- Since you have mentioned in your comment that you can switch to a different IDE, please check [Spyder](https://www.spyder-ide.org/)